# How to analysis a design for grid layout?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, web, responsive-design

Some one told me that some of designs doesn't support grid system layout like bootstrap, foundations etc, so i am not sure what thing need to analysis in design before to get started any, i know bootstrap this is 12 columns grid system but not sure how to analysis for example i have attached a image of a web design can any body explain me how i can analysis this before get started.
Also client is talking about to make it 1600px on large view.
[Image linke](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XpXwc.jpg)

Comment: Create your own layout. I wouldn't just go by the 'plugins' available to me. I'd rather build the thing myself (that way, i know exactly the way things *should* look, since i coded it)

Comment: I am new here i am totally shock no one is answering me just voting down why?

Comment: @jbutler483 this is not answer of my question please read again my question.

Comment: Did you take the tour first? Or even read the *how to ask* section?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To analysis with design you can see the section how much they section have each section should have one grid with for example with bootstrap you can make 12 columns theme and your theme is with two section this mean this two columns theme. If you want more help please ask.

Comment: is this mean if i have more than 13 section bootstrap will not help me to develop my design.

Comment: No by changing `LESS` you can change any design according to yours.